# how to close a running socket thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, serversocket

I am running a server that enables multiple socket connections.
i am trying to shut down the thread when the client side terminated the connection.

this is the code for the client thread:

```
class ClientThread implements Runnable {
    Socket threadSocket;
    private boolean chk = false, stop = false, sendchk = false, running = true;
    DataOutputStream out = null;

    //This constructor will be passed the socket
    public ClientThread(Socket socket){
        threadSocket = socket;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("New connection at " + new Date() + "\n");
        try {
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream (threadSocket.getInputStream());
            out = new DataOutputStream (threadSocket.getOutputStream());                  
            while (running){
                // read input from client
                int ln = in.available();
                byte [] bytes  = new byte [ln];
                in.read(bytes);
                String msg = new String(bytes);

                // parse in going message
                messageParsing(msg);

                // respond to client
                response();

                /////////////////////////////
                ////// this is the part that i thought would help me close the thread
                ////////////////////////////
                if (threadSocket.isInputShutdown()){
                    running = false;
                }
            }
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) {System.out.println(ex);}
        finally {
            try {
                threadSocket.close();
                System.out.println("Connection closed due to unauthorized entry.\n");
            } catch (IOException ex) {System.out.println(ex);}
        }
    }}
```

However, the `if` statement does not do the trick. The thread is still running  and tries to send/read data from the socket.
How can make it work? what am i missing?
any help would be appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isInputShutdown()` tells you whether *you* have shutdown the input of this socket. It doesn't have anything to do with the peer.

Your problem is that you are ignoring the result of the `read()` method. If it returns -1, the peer has closed the connection.

NB Your use of `available()` is also incorrect. Just read into a fixed sized buffer.

You can greatly simplify your code.

Comment: how am i able to read into a fixed size buffer if i don't know it? Before the `available()` i was using `readInt()` but it was working only if the client sends the size of the data before the actual data.

Comment: your solution is working, however it seems to be closing the connection in times it shouldn't have. is the a way to set something like a time out during which the connection wont be recognized as terminated?

Comment: You just read and then do `new String(buffer, 0, count)` where `count` is the value returned by `read()`. Of course it isn't guaranteed to be an entire application message. There's nothing in my 'solution' that closes the connection at all. It should be closed when you get -1 or an `IOException` from `read()`. Do you mean the *peer* closes it unexpectedly? Nothing you can do about that at this end.

Comment: thanx, i  did the exception catching thing. I close the thread  when i can not  send any responses back to the client.